# FB Friend Picker View Controller with custom table cells

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a subclass of Facebook's FBFriendPickerViewController in an iOS app.  Is there a way to customize the look of that?  I see the customizations that can be made for selecting a single friend, etc.  I want to replace the headers and table cells.  Using the FacebookSDK.framework it looks like the headers for FBGraphObjectTableCell and the associated data source are not included.  How can I customize this?

If that's not an option, I'm not opposed to doing my own picker, but how can I sort friends using the graph api?  I'd rather paginate them in that case and I need them to be in order by name.  I've played around with doing this using fql, but the return data isn't as easy to manage as these FBGraphObjects.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem...
In my situation I chose to have my own picker, do a query in FQL to get all the friends, order them by a comparator and then divide them in two groups (two arrays, users with app and users without app) and pass those values to the controller (which is a tableview delegate and tabledatasource delegate).

The problem I am facing is image loading. I've tried AFNetworking and SDWebImage but the view seems to be freezing from time to time and slow. After a while everything works... but that's not optimal.

Let me know if you find out any other way to achieve your goal, I would be really interested to know another method!

Comment: Sorry..I've just found this: [https://github.com/emreberge/My-Facebook-Friends](https://github.com/emreberge/My-Facebook-Friends), maybe it could be helpful!